# yii2 restful prevent specific fields from update

Tags: rest, yii2

I'm developing an app for mobile phones using the restful api of yii2 to perform CRUD operations.
I need that when sending an updated request (PUT OR PATCH) it is only possible to update a certain number of fields, for example name and address, so, if the user tries to update more fields, such as id, name, address and email, the api returns an error.
Someone can guide me a little?
Thanks for read.

Comment: You can set up [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) to prevent users change data you don't want to.

Comment: That sounds good. I don't know how the scenarios work because I haven't needed to use them, I guess there's always a first time. I'm going to try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Yupik, it works great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using scenarios inside your model.

Check this example, it will explain it for you

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/

Hope that will be helpful!

Comment: Thank you, it's very useful.

Comment: You're welcome!!
Please mark my answer as Accepted Answer if the solution helps. Thank you.